# CollectionFS not displaying image until refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, amazon-s3, meteor

I am using CollectionFS with cfs-ejson-file as I am storing the image in a imageObj field on my collection.

I am also using cfs-s3.

The images upload successfully however I thought TempStorage was used until the s3 version is avaiablie. As soon as I am taken to the page for the item I don't see the image until I refresh the page.

Do I have to get the temporary version differently?

This is how  I currently get the image:

```
Template.listingPage.helpers({
    photo: function(){
        return this.imageObj.getFileRecord();

    }
});
```

Comment: are you using a custom mongodb url?

Comment: fixed by using Images.findOne(this.imageObj._id) instead

Comment: @theo3335796 I'm having a similar issue, can you take a peak? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577567/collectionfs-not-displaying-image-until-page-is-refreshed